# How to ingest streaming websocket data into AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, websocket, amazon-ecs, amazon-kinesis

My goal is to connect to various websockets (30 more or less) and save the raw data into S3 in the cheapest and most efficient way possible.

I know that there is Kinesis to capture and process streaming data.

What I'm missing is what comes before Kinesis, since I need a program running that listens to the WS Connection and forwards the data into kinesis.

I have tried using an EC2 instance and containers on Fargate to run the websocket connections and both options work.

I was wondering if there is another way (recommended way) of doing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The only other option I'm aware of is AWS API Gateway + Lambda. API Gateway maintains the persistent websocket connection, and passes data into your Lambda function as it comes in. That solution would be cheaper if you are only receiving data occasionally. But if you are receiving a constant stream of data from 30 websockets, ECS is probably cheaper.